# Switch between panes in Pharo v3

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, smalltalk, pharo

While at the System Browser I can switch between panes and buttons using alt+tab and arrows, but once I'm at the "method editing" pane I can't go out of it using keyboard shortcuts. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can switch the focus to the other panels:

```
cmd+g+c focus class list
cmd+g+p focus package list
cmd+g+m focus method list
cmd+g+t focus protocol list
cmd+g+s focus source code panel
```

in the window menu (little arrow icon on the title pane) is a menu entry
for the shortcuts description

Answer (score 2):

This is a well-known issue. KeyMapping is being overhauled. You can add your own for the moment.

Take a look at the class side of AbstractNautilusUI

Comment: So following your advice looking at the existing classes i was able (after a while) to implement all the shortuts i wanted. Thank you!